# Meaning of "in" in the phrase "in imitation of"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

***They discussed important issues (in) imitation of their elders.***

—From COLLINS DICTIONARY

I want to know the meaning of "in" Preposition in the above sentence.

What I found (Based on my research) *in* is describing  "*manner or as a consequence of something or result*".(I may be wrong because it's my guess only.) I want to know as to its correct usage with respect to its meaning in the sentence.

Comment: You don't normally stick a noun or noun phrase on the end of a sentence unless it's a direct or indirect object (an exception might be some time phrases). You need a preposition.

Comment: Where does the quote "manner or as a consequence of something or result" come from? How does it begin? I don't think "manner" is the first word if it's supposed to define a preposition.

Comment: @gotube   ("Manner" is not the dictionary definition, I was thinking the phrase describing the manner of their discussing important issues)(But as I said I may be wrong because it's my guess )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'In imitation', 'in praise', 'in commiseration', etc - we can use 'in' as a preposition to indicate a motivation or reason for an action.

The people mentioned ('they') discussed important issues because they liked to, or wanted to, act like their elders (imitate them)

> PREPOSITION B2
>
> You use in to indicate the feeling or desire which someone has when
> they do something, or which causes them to do it.
>
> *Simpson looked at them in surprise.*
>
> *Chris was weeping in anger and grief.*
>
> *Carl pushed ahead in his eagerness to reach the wall.*

[In (states and qualities) - Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in)

Comment: Thanks, btw my research findings are fine??

Comment: @Sam No, in your sample sentence, they did not discuss issues either in the **manner** of imitating their elders nor as a **consequence** of imitating their elders. Rather, they discussed issues with a **desire** to imitate their elders. The definition you quote refers to usages like "***In** failing to file his taxes, Capone exposed himself to criminal prosecution*", where "in failing" means *as a consequence of failing*.

Comment: @Sam - er, that's what gotube already wrote.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I had the doubt that Why I can't say "As a consequence of Imitating their elders, they discussed important issues."?

Comment: @gotube The usage of preposition "in" in the phase "in imitation of" ( I think) is similar to "in" in the phase " in honour of " (In the sense "used to indicate goal or purpose")

Comment: @Sam Yes, very similar. In "in honour of", "in" indicates a feeling or purpose behind an action. I think it's the same definition as "in imitation of".